# Dockerfile 'COPY' command not copying files

Tags: linux, docker, node.js

I am running into a frustrating problem when trying to create and run a new docker container. When I upload my code to a Github repository and then use Docker Hub to build it, the build completes without any errors. However, when I try to create and then run the new container on my own server I find that the necessary files and directories have not been copied into the new container or into the local directories that were bound to the container directories (obviously). Strangely though, it does seem that the `init.sh` script referenced at the end of my Dockerfile *is* being copied because it runs, but it fails because the other files that were supposed to be copied into the `WORKDIR` are not there. I've tried different files structures and `COPY` commands to no avail, and all of the files and directories to be copied are in the root of the repository at the moment. Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN \
  npm install -g @adonisjs/cli && \
  npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/

VOLUME /usr/src/app

RUN \
  cp /usr/src/app/init.sh /usr/local/bin/ && \
  chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/init.sh && \
  ln -s usr/local/bin/init.sh / # backwards compat

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/init.sh"]
```

And my docker create and docker run commands:

```
docker create --name='ferdi-server' -p '3333:80' -v '/mnt/cache/appdata/ferdi-server':'/usr/src/app' 'xthursdayx/ferdi-server-docker' 

docker run -d --name='ferdi-server' -p '3333:80' -v '/mnt/cache/appdata/ferdi-server':'/usr/src/app' 'xthursdayx/ferdi-server-docker'
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to figure this out for two days and am at a dead end.

FYI here are the file structures and COPY commands I've most recently tried

```
├── Dockerfile
├── init.sh
│   └── api
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── .env.example
│       ├── etc
│       ├── init.sh
│       └── app
│       |   └── directory
│       └── config
│           └── app.js
│           └── etc.js
```

with command  `COPY api/ /usr/src/app/`

and

```
├── Dockerfile
├── init.sh
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── .env.example
├── etc
├── init.sh
│   └── app
│   └── directory2
│   └── config
│       └── app.js
│       └── etc.js
```

with command  `COPY . /usr/src/app/`

Comment: You have a folder `init.sh`? Are the files present in the build context aka the folder from which you start the build command? Maybe try `COPY ./ ./`. The slash can make a big difference! The first dot is the build context on your host. The second dot is the working directory inside your image and container. Btw: you don't need mkdir before WORKDIR IIRC.

Comment: I noticed that you are coping data to `/usr/src/app/` and also you are mounting `/mnt/cache/appdata/ferdi-server` to `/usr/src/app/`. Its possible that data is being copied but might have been overwritten when you ran the `docker run` command.

Comment: Can you try just launching the image with plain bash shell without any mounts and see if your data is there `docker run -it <image name> bash`

Comment: @uav sorry, that was a typo, there is no init.sh folder, the folder in the second file structure should be app. Thanks for the info about the mkdir command for WORKDIR. I thought it might be unnecessary, but I wasn't sure. I have been using Docker Hub to automatically build/update the container when the code is changed in my github repo. I then just run a `docker run` command on my own server. So, the files/structure/code are present on Github/Docker Hub. I just tried building it locally and the container refuses still refuses to start, and it doesn't appear that the files are being copied.

Comment: Please consider the other two suggestions. Don't be angry with me, but if you screw around with the output of `tree`, you will quickly be sorted into the troll category.

Comment: I think it should be pretty obvious that i'm not trolling. I just built the file structure tree from memory to show what it looked it, since the containers aren't actually able to be start.

Comment: @GauravPundir thanks for the suggestions. I just launchd the image again without /usr/src/app mounted to the host and a plain bash shell and was able to see the correct files in /usr/src/app. So, I guess my next question then is how I can externally mount this directory without overwriting it when I run the `docker run` command.